# how to sort an array based on previous numerical keys?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I would like to sort an array to reindex its keys.
I tried using custom loop but it does not work.
Is there a php function to do this?
I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 44
            [name] => 1495714823.jpg
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 48
            [name] => 1495795384.jpg
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
            [name] => 1495602099.jpg
        )
)
```

I need to sort array like this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 48
            [name] => 1495795384.jpg
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
            [name] => 1495602099.jpg
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 44
            [name] => 1495714823.jpg
        )
)
```

i tried some of the sort functions but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need [ksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)

```
ksort($array);
```

This should give you the output you are looking for.
See here for output: https://3v4l.org/hgv4F